# How to get elements from an Object[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I have the following lines of Java code:

```
Object[] results = api.getProjects();
   for(int i=0; i<results.length; i++){
       System.out.println(results[i].toString());
   }
```

An here it is the output:

```
TestProject [id=1, name=Test Plan, prefix=MA, notes=, enableRequirements=true, enableTestPriority=true, enableAutomation=true, enableInventory=true, isActive=true, isPublic=true]
```

My concern is how I can get only the wanted elements? (i.e: "name" and "id")

Comment: You don't. You have to use or cast to the appropriate type and use whatever methods it provides (or access its public fields directly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should typecast each object and print whats necessary.

Assume that each of the elements of array result could be typecasted to TestProject class. You can follow this apporach :

```
Object[] results = api.getProjects();
for(TestProject tp : results){    
   System.out.println(tp.getName + " " + tp.getId());
 }
```

Or

```
 Object[] results = api.getProjects();
    for(Object tp : results){    
       String name = ((TestProject)tp).getName() ;
       String id = ((TestProject)tp).getId() ;
       System.out.println(name);
       System.out.println(id);
     }
```

Your existing implementation would also work.,if you override toString() as

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   return "TestProject [id=" + id + ", name=" + name +"]"; 
}
```

Comment: Fixed the type for the casting in the second example.

Comment: @znupii : Which one you applied?

Comment: This one: `Object[] results = api.getProjects();
    for(Object tp : results){    
       String name = ((TestProject)tp).getName() ;
       String id = ((TestProject)tp).getId() ;
       System.out.println(name);
       System.out.println(id);
     }`

Comment: Where did those `getName()` and `getId()` come from?

Answer (score 2):

As you want only id and name. Therefore, id is at the index[0] and name is at the index[1]. Therefore the code will be like this.

```
   Object[] results = api.getProjects();
   System.out.println(results[0]);
   System.out.println(results[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object[] results` is a bad choice for this.

Individual elements look to be either classes or HashMaps

Assuming former, you can do something like this

```
Result[] results = api.getProjects()

result[i].name
result[i].id
```